# ffmpeg: Cut a video to get an output of a given size

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm currently developing a ffmpeg App and I want to divide a video in parts of a given size, for instance, divide a video of 200Mb in parts of 50Mb each one, any idea how to do it so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using this command to cut a part of the video ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -ss 00:05:40 -t 00:00:10 -async 1 "output_cut.mp4" but I want to aim to a give size, I'm not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg does have a `-fs` parameter to stop writing after a specific number of bytes. But it may be tricky to parse out the last frame it wrote and then create a different segment starting at the end point.

Instead, consider using the [`segment` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) which creates a series of files from a single stream. It splits by duration rather than size, but you can calculate the approximate duration/size ratio by setting your audio/video bitrate (i.e. `-b:v 896k -b:a 128k` for *approximately* 1 MB/second), then set your `-segment_time` accordingly. Note that you may need to tweak the settings to make sure the segments are self-contained and in the format you want.

By the way, if you just want to copy the stream without transcoding you need to add `-c copy` in to your argument, but I wouldn't recommend it if you don't know what kind of input you're getting.